# Jtable cell font color based on cell value

Tags: jtable

```
class CustomTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
          String s = table.getModel().getValueAt(row,12).toString();                    
            if(s.equals("Filled") && column == 12)
            {
                setForeground(Color.RED);


                System.out.println("Inside " + s + column);
            }

        return c;
    }}
```

Using above code, color of all columns chaging, I want to change on single column based on value.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the above question. I got the answer for the same.